# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. After setting useState value

Tags: reactjs, render, use-state

The error: `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` occurred after...

I changed my code from this:

```
if(location.state.name !== undefined || location.state.Username !== undefined){
  console.log(location.state.name);
} else{
  console.log("Nothing");
}
```

to this:

```
if(location.state.name !== undefined || location.state.Username !== undefined){
  setName(location.state.name);
} else{
  console.log("Nothing");
}
```

Where `name, setName` are empty useState string, and after setting name value as `location.state.name` which is a string that contains a username.

Comment: Can you show us your `useEffect` call and it’s dependency array? You’re running into an infinite loop here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got this logic running on render, and you're rendering the state variable `name`, which is causing an infinite loop. You're setting state with `setName(location.state.name)`, and when you set state you trigger a re-render of the component. Then on re-render, it's re-running this logic, setting the state, which triggers a re-render.....

If you only want to do this code once on page render, it needs to be inside a useEffect hook with no args (for functional component):

> ```
> useEffect( () => {
>   if (location.state.name !== undefined) {
>     setName(location.state.name);
>   } else {
>     console.log("Nothing");
>   }), [] );
> ```

or in a componentDidMount() (for class component):

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>  //your same logic
> }
> ```